# NPE in an impossible place

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I'm having this super weird NPE:

> Technical Exception : stack error
> #java.lang.NullPointerException  at
> packagename.addTraceIdToThreadContext(XXX.java:115) at
> ...

```
111    public void addTraceIdToThreadContext(String traceId) {
      ...
114        if (nonNull(this.logContext)) {
115            this.logContext.setTraceId(traceId);
116        }
117    }
```

(Thanks for the comments, the XXX.java is in singleton, the web app is under JBoss, nonNull method is imported from Objects class)

I suppose the line number in the stacktrace is correct?
Any idea please? Thanks

Comment: Is the `nonNull` the `nonNull` of the `Objects` class?

Comment: Concurrent modification from different threads? setting logContext to null after passing the if-condition and prior to setting the value would be possible.

Comment: @user2999226 yes it is.

Comment: @Simulant this XXX.java is in singleton, and I think it is not in MultiThreads

Comment: Please show the full stack trace, the declaration of `logContext` and any methods of XXX which assign values to `logContext`.

Comment: Also, is this error occasional, or does it happen every time `addTraceIdToThreadContext` is called?

Comment: Incidentally, why are you using `nonNull` instead of `!= null`?

Comment: @tgdavies For the moment it happened only once. nonNull is used everywhere in this application, so it's not critical, just an habit. I'll try to put more details. It's a little long

Comment: Try synchronization.

Comment: Definitely sounds like a concurrency problem.

Comment: It is not good practice to use Objects.nonNull in place of ordinary operators.  Do you also use `Integer.sum(a, b)` instead of `a + b`?

Comment: "the application(web app under JBoss) is not in multithreads" a jboss web app is very likely to be running a thread per http request.

Comment: "the application(web app under JBoss) is not in multithreads" - even the name of your method suggests multiple threads!

Comment: @k314159 good point. But I still don't get it. This class is in singleton, If nonNull(this.logContext) return true, why the logContext instance becomes null later in this.logContext.setTraceId(traceId). It means the instance is destroyed?

Comment: @tgdavies yes you are right. As I said to k314159, I still don't get it.

Comment: You have not provided enough information for anyone to explain this behaviour. Please show the full stack trace, the declaration of logContext and any methods of XXX which assign values to logContext

Comment: Another thread is setting `logContext` to `null` between the time the check is done and the time the value is used. The answer is as simple as that. But you need to explain what `logContext` is and what its lifecycle should be before anyone can explain what the solution should be.

Comment: @tgdavies Sorry I was too busy yesterday. The code and stacktraces contain many info of my company, I need to remove them. Please give me a little time. Sorry

Comment: @VGR I know nonNull takes a little more time than !=null, it was not my decision to use it.

Comment: @tgdavies Oh I found it. Exactly what you said. I'll put it in the answer. Thank you so much.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @tgdavies, I found the reason.

In the same class there's a method which can set the logContext to null:

```
    public static SmaUtils getInstance(String moduleName) {
    ((SmaUtilsImpl) INSTANCE).logContext = null;
    ((SmaUtilsImpl) INSTANCE).moduleName = moduleName;
    return INSTANCE;
}
```

A second thread set the logContext to null while the first thread arrives between these 2 lines:

```
114 if (nonNull(this.logContext)) {
115     this.logContext.setTraceId(traceId);
```

The solution would be synchronized it but I'll review the code why we have this method which set the logContext to null.

Comment: You can surround the `if` with `synchronised(this) { ... }`. But is `logContext` becoming `null` from one thread while another thread is trying to set the `traceId` what you want? This feels like an error in your requirements or design.

Comment: @tgdavies Agree, I suppose it is a design error. I'll check why we have this method which could set the logContext to null.